# Linebreak without justification if remaining Text doesn't fit

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I have a text (justified block paragraph) with an author attribution.

If the last line of the text has enough space left to fit the author attribution and some space, then it should be put into that line flushed right.

If the last line of the text doesn't have enough space, the author attribution should go to the next line flushed right, but the last line of the paragraph shouldn't be justified.

```
Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. 
Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. 
Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar.   by the Author

Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. 
Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. 
Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar. Foo bar foobar.
                                              by another Author
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think the amsthm `proof` environment uses similar logic to position the QED symbol at the end of a proof -- maybe look at its implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\def\signed#1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
    \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil #1%
    \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}

\begin{document}

Phasellus sagittis blandit tortor, vitae facilisis nisl molestie a. Proin
suscipit, purus in scelerisque bibendum, ligula magna hendrerit mauris, et
condimentum libero dui a tortor. ligula magna hendrerit mauris. \signed{A. Uthor}

\bigskip

Scelerisque bibendum, ligula magna hendrerit mauris, et
condimentum libero dui a tortor Phasellus. \signed{A. Uthor}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should cite the source. ;-)

Comment: You are right, this is not code that I wrote but found in same package and then used in my own documents. Shame on me, I don't remember which package it was. But I guess you know ;)

Comment: Yes, it's in the TeXbook. Look for Bourbaki in the index (or directly at page 106).